# Laravel Database many:one relation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning laravel and building a small blog application to practice.

I have a 'posts' table with the following structure:

```
id:int AI
post:text
author:int
```

And a comments table with the following structure:

```
id:int AI
comment:text
author:int
post:int
```

Where the post field in the comments table is meant to link the comment to the its post.

Now, in order to add a comment, I would add a form in my `show.blade.php` file in the views/posts directory and point it to the `store@CommentsController` metod. A hidden field of the view would be automatically populated with the post's ID, so that my store method in Comments Controlelr could look something like:

```
Post::find(id)->comments->save($comment);
```

(I'd have already defined the relations between the tables in the model fiels, and $comment would be something like `$comment = Comment::create($comment_data_from_form)` )

That would be all and well, however, I was wondering if laravel had some nicer way of passing the id of the post from the post view to the comments controller than having to specify and populate a hidden field?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a route with the post id as a parameter.

To create a new comment for a post you could use a route like following.

```
http://example.org/posts/{id}/comments
```

and in your controller

```
public function store($postId)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($postId);
    ...
    $post->comments->save($comment);
}
```